# Program to assign last names to groups help-

Tags: c++

so this program that I'm writing takes in a first and last name from the user, and based on the initial of the last name, places them into group 1,2 or 3. But, my program bases it off the initial of the first name and I'm confused on why its doing that, any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string name="";
   string letter="";
   int finder=0;
   cout << "Enter a first and last name:" << endl;
   getline(cin, name); //gets user input


  for(int count = 0; count<=10; ){

  finder = name.find(" ",1);
   letter = name.substr(finder,2);

   if(letter>="A" && letter <="I"){

   cout << name << " is in group 1" <<endl;
   return 0;
   }

   else if(letter>="J" && letter <="S"){
   cout << name << " is in group 2" <<endl;
   return 0;
   }

   else if(letter>="T" && letter <="Z"){
   cout << name << " is in group 3" <<endl;
   return 0;
   }
  }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program takes two characters for letter - the space before the last names letter, and the last name's first letter.

If you change the line to `letter = name.substr(finder + 1, 1);` It seems to have the desired result of grouping based on first letter of last name.